# what is meant by fallback color in css

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I want to know the mean of fallback color?By googling i came to know that a fallback color is the one which will display and replace the color format when the format given is not supported by the browsers(Internet Explorer).Am I right.?or any more features are there.let me know.

Actually iam not much clear about fallback.so if possible give an example.

Thank you.

Comment: That's basically it. I don't think there's a definition as such but it's basic english.. Look at the comment here which says `fallback color if gradients are not supported` [MDN Comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Cross-browser_gradients)

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 5):

You are right, a fallback color is a CSS property or value a browser will "fall back" to when it doesn't know how to render another. CSS reads style rules from top to bottom, so you want your fallback property to come **before** your desired property. For example:

```
div {
   background: rgb(135, 206, 250); /* The Fallback */
   background: rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.7); 
}
```

IE8, which doesn't support rgba (essentially rgb with transparency) will get to the rgba line, and not recognizing the value, will "fall back" to the last available value for that property, in this case rgb. Modern browsers will first apply rgb and then move to the next line and overwrite it with rgba.

Comment: yes.i gone through the answer and i got it.Thank You.

Comment: @user5945554 then please mark this question as answered